# Cleaning around a fixed wire retainer

Tags: cleaning, personal-care

Having had orthodontic treatment, I now have both Essix retainers and the fixed wire retainers. Try as I might, I'm finding it hard to keep my teeth clean, particularly the backs of the six front teeth (I guess I got used to 30 years of having the teeth in the same place and am having problems adjusting), and the wire retainer requires special care. Are there any hacks that apply to cleaning the backs of these teeth, especially the very narrow area between the wire and the gums?

Comment: Are gross questions on topic?

Answer (score 2):

I use a dental irrigator twice a day after brushing & flossing. It gets into spots that are hard or impossible to reach with a toothbrush or floss, including any pockets around the base of the tooth.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it would fit, but you could get a bottle nipple cleaner from Wal-mart or Target or wherever you prefer.  It looks like a twisted wire with bristles coming off of it and is found in the baby section.  It is small enough to clean inside the nipples of a baby bottle so, if it is small enough, it might fit between the retainer and your teeth.